# Parsing html tables content with Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get content of the first html table there is in file and write it to .txt in some human readable form. I found [this](http://segfault.in/2010/07/parsing-html-table-in-python-with-beautifulsoup/) tutorial and modified it a little to get input from files and put output results into different files.

The problem is that it's 4 years old and apparently out of date. I figured out findAll is now called find_all but I don't know why I can't iterate through the table. So for I've got:

```
def function(number_of_files):

    for i in range(1, number_of_files):
        input = open('html/' + str(i) + '.html')

        soup = BeautifulSoup(input)
        table = soup.find('table')
        rows = table.find_all('tr')

        output = open('output/' + str(i) + '.txt', 'wb')

        for tr in rows:
            columns = tr.findAll('td')
            for td in columns:
                text = ''.join(td.find(text=True))
                output.writelines(text)
            print '\n'
```

But it returns error:

```
rows = table.find_all('tr')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

What can I do about it?

Comment: Can you provide the input file please? It is not in the link you gave.

Comment: Obviously, `find()` method has found no 'table' occurences. - That means, that your file contains none. Could you provide the file you're parsing?

Comment: Well, you are right. I was parsing a lot of files and some of them containted 'table' occurance and some didn't. Simple if (table != None) solved the problem. Thanks for help.